# Why can't I identify the false?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to fail on purpose... According to the documentation `get_term_by` will return `false` when nothing is found.

I issue:

```
$exiting_term = get_term_by('slug', sanitize_title("something"), 'non-existing-one');
```

Then I...

```
var_dump($existing_term);
```

The output from which is:

```
bool(false)
```

However, my code will *not* to into this block. Why is that?

```
if ($existing_term === false) {
 /// NEVER GETS HERE.
}
```

Comment: `$exiting_term != $existing_term`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo.

```
var_dump('exiting_term' == 'existing_term');
--> bool(false)
```

Comment: You are correct... and I need glasses. Thanks!

Comment: @JasonGenX not only that - you also need to enable logging notices

Comment: @zerkms I'm inclined to blame WordPress for that bit.

Comment: WordPress provides tools for this so it's not to blame. It's OP's fault for not using them.

Comment: @cabrerahector I still think WP has a cavalier attitude towards error reporting. https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/6fd8080e7ee7599b36d4528f72a8ced612130b8c/wp-load.php#L24

Comment: @ceejayoz jeez, my eyes are bleeding now. But point taken, not much to do there for a regular developer.